# EC2 SSH timeout but SFTP ok

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I was using one of my ec2 instances for a node.js project. I have been working on it off and on for 2 weeks. Last night I sit down at the console hit the up key a few times to bring up the often used

```
ssh -i ~/Dev/path2/key.pem ubuntu@11.11.11.11
```

Connection times out and won't connect.
So I go to my ec2 panel and the server is running.
I check my security and I have everything locked to my ip. I like to take out all question so I changed it to accept ssh from anywhere.
I go back and time out. Then I notice filezilla is still open. I test it and it works. I disconnect, reconnect it works. Of course it is using the .ppk key but I'm not getting an auth error just timing out.
I pinged the server and failed but then I read you may not be able to ping amazon ec2 instances unless you allow that connection and I only have ssh and http open.
I restarted my console. 
I rebooted the server.
No ssh.

To test I spun up another instance. I ssh in and installed node.js I made a directory and I can SFTP in from filezilla. Everything is fine. Is there an obvious setting I switched?

Comment: What is the permission of ~/Dev/path2/key.pem ? Also check the ssh logs in the server. You can use MindTerm to connect to the server :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/computebasics-linux/connect-from-browser.html

Comment: 0400. Unfortunately I had to take the server down as I couldn't afford a server I couldn't ssh into. I wish I had tried MindTerm. How is SFTP working from my IP and not SSH from a Bash shell. If MindTerm had worked it may have offered some clues. I spun up replacements and all are working fine. Thank you all.